# Android updating Visualizer audio session ID

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I have an application that plays audio files from MediaPlayer class.

I have attached a Visualizer to the current audio session ID, which works fine.

When I change audio track, and thus changing the audio session ID, i need to re-create the Visualizer because I can not find a method to set the new audio session ID.

This creates a problem that a new VisualizerView gets added to my layout. How do I update the current audio session ID, alternatively remove the current instance of the VisualizerView and add the new one?

Code:

```
public class PlaySongActivity extends Activity{
    private static final float VISUALIZER_HEIGHT_DIP = 50f;
    private Visualizer mVisualizer;
    private VisualizerView mVisualizerView;
    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_song);

        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutViewVisualizer);

        playSong();
    } 

    /* Below methods are used with buttons to play/play next/play previous song */

    private void playSong(Bundle extras) {
        //playing music from a service
        service.playMusic();
        setupVisualizerFx();
        mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void playPreviousSong() {
        service.playPrevious();
        setupVisualizerFx();
        mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void playNextSong() {
        service.playNext();
        setupVisualizerFx();
        mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);
    }

/* 
 * Below code that is used for the Visualizer is taken from: 
 * http://www.vogella.com/code/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/AudioFxDemo.html
 */

private void setupVisualizerFx() {        
    // Create a VisualizerView (defined below), which will render the simplified audio
    // wave form to a Canvas.
    mVisualizerView = new VisualizerView(this);
    mVisualizerView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            (int)(VISUALIZER_HEIGHT_DIP * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)));
    mLinearLayout.addView(mVisualizerView);
    // Create the Visualizer object and attach it to 
    int audioSessionId = service.getAudioSessionId();
    mVisualizer = new Visualizer(audioSessionId);
    mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);
    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener() {
        public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
                int samplingRate) {
            mVisualizerView.updateVisualizer(bytes);
        }

        public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {}
    }, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, false);
}

/**
 * A simple class that draws waveform data received from a
 * {@link Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener#onWaveFormDataCapture }
 */
class VisualizerView extends View {
    private byte[] mBytes;
    private float[] mPoints;
    private Rect mRect = new Rect();

    private Paint mForePaint = new Paint();

    public VisualizerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mBytes = null;

        mForePaint.setStrokeWidth(1f);
        mForePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mForePaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    }

    public void updateVisualizer(byte[] bytes) {
        mBytes = bytes;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (mBytes == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mPoints == null || mPoints.length < mBytes.length * 4) {
            mPoints = new float[mBytes.length * 4];
        }

        mRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        for (int i = 0; i < mBytes.length - 1; i++) {
            mPoints[i * 4] = mRect.width() * i / (mBytes.length - 1);
            mPoints[i * 4 + 1] = mRect.height() / 2
                    + ((byte) (mBytes[i] + 128)) * (mRect.height() / 2) / 128;
            mPoints[i * 4 + 2] = mRect.width() * (i + 1) / (mBytes.length - 1);
            mPoints[i * 4 + 3] = mRect.height() / 2
                    + ((byte) (mBytes[i + 1] + 128)) * (mRect.height() / 2) / 128;
        }

        canvas.drawLines(mPoints, mForePaint);
    }
}

}
```

this is the current result of my code, when calling playNext() or playPrevious():

[image: result]

As you can see the VisualizerViews keep piling up on each other. I'd want for the new VisualizerView to replace the old one, alternatively update the audio session ID for the current one, if that is possible. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Marcus

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved this by adding these lines of code in the setupVisualizerFx() method:

```
if(mVisualizer != null)
        mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
```

now the method looks like:

```
private void setupVisualizerFx() {      
    if(mVisualizer != null)
        mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);
    // Create the Visualizer object and attach it to 
    int audioSessionId = service.getAudioSessionId();
    mVisualizer = new Visualizer(audioSessionId);

    mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);
    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener() {
        public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
                int samplingRate) {
            mVisualizerView.updateVisualizer(bytes);
        }

        public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {}
    }, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, false);
}
```

Edit: some code was moved to the onCreate method instead